# ASP.NET Connection time out after being idle for a while

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling

My ASP.NET website while trying to connect to the database for first time after a period of inactivity throws an time out exception.
I understand the connections in the connection pool get terminated after some idle time for some reason (Firewall or Oracle settings) and the pool or app doesn't have a clue about it.

Is there any way to validate the connection beforehand so that the first try doesn't throw an exception?
I don't have much control over the DB or Firewall settings. So I have to deal with this is my application.(would prefer if there is any web.config settings)

I am using: ASP.NET 2.0. Oracle server 11g, Microsoft Enterprise Library DAAB to do all my DB operations.

*I did some search on this topic but didnt find any solid solution for this yet*  :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a State property on SqlConnection that you could check

```
if(myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
 // perform your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always increase the [Connection Timeout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)